# SQL SSMS - find and flag existing record and flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have 2 tables, structure as follows:

**Table1:**

```
Data_Details_Fk Date_Fk Entity_Fk   Scenario_Fk Value
60              3652    13          2           10
56              3652    11          2           81
58              3652    10          2           43
57              3652    12          3           79
59              3652    14          2           27
59              3652    10          2           49
59              3652    10          3           76
58              3652    10          3           35
56              3652    11          3           44
57              3652    11          2           40
```

**Table2:**

```
Data_Details_Sk Rtype
60              PL
56              PL
58              BS
57              BS
59              CF
```

I have 2 scenarios i.e. 2 refers to actual and 3 refers to budget.
I want to flag my table with additional column that would say that flag row with 1 when same `Data_Details_Fk, Date_Fk, Entity_Fk` record exist for scenario 2,3 considering `Rtype`.

Flag all the budget where combination of actual is available on entity, datadetails (Not really on DataDetails but RType as a join).
Rtype would be basically the report for PL, BS, CF loaded for data_details_fk.

**Output required is:**

```
Data_Details_Fk Date_Fk Entity_Fk   Scenario_Fk Value   IsFlag
60              3652    13              2       10      0
56              3652    11              2       81      1
58              3652    10              2       43      1
57              3652    12              3       79      0
59              3652    14              2       27      0
59              3652    10              2       49      1
59              3652    10              3       76      1
58              3652    10              3       35      1
56              3652    11              3       44      1
57              3652    11              2       40      0
```

I have a big size table and want to optimize the query to take the least time on populating the flag.

Comment: I am quite confused by the description.  What is `Scenario_FK`?  Why doesn't `RType` take on values of 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that I'm a bit confused by the question.  The results suggest that you want to flag rows as 1 when `Scenario_FK` has both 0 and 1 for the combination of other columns.  If this is correct and only values of 2 and 3 are permitted, then one way is:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when min(Scenario_Fk) over (partition by Data_Details_Fk, Date_Fk, Entity_Fk) = 2 and
                  max(Scenario_Fk) over (partition by Data_Details_Fk, Date_Fk, Entity_Fk) = 3
             then 1 else 0
        end) as isFlag
from table1 t1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,Thanks for prompt reply. Question is that I want to only flag the rows where data_details_fk, entity_fk and date_fk exist for both scenario 2 and 3. Also there are more scenarios but I want to only consider 2 and 3 when doing this. Will be great help if You could help me out.

Comment: @NikyRathod . . . New question should be asked as questions, not in comments.